# What is the difference between IPv6 addresses :: and ::1?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, localhost

Maybe this is a silly question but sometimes I see IPv6 `::` to mean the local host, and sometimes I see `::1`. Occasionally, using one vs. the other seems to be the difference between something working and something not working.

What is the difference between `::` and `::1`? Are there any differences that might come into play if a machine has multiple network interfaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::1` is the true "local host" or "loopback" address, equivalent to `127.0.0.1` in IPv4.

`::` is the "unspecified" or "null" address, equivalent to `0.0.0.0` in IPv4. Its main purpose is to refer to *all* possible local addresses when binding a socket to a local address – doing so is the *opposite* of using the loopback address.

The "unspecified" address does not mean "local host" officially – as far as I know, connecting *to* the unspecified address is not meant to be a valid operation, neither for `[::]` nor `0.0.0.0`. (However, some operating systems accept it nevertheless – for example, in the Linux source code, there is a special case that handles connections to 0.0.0.0 as if they were connections to 127.0.0.1 with a comment saying "For compatibility with BSD", and it has similar handling for [::] simply to remain consistent with IPv4.)